# Polymer Single template instances not updating

Tags: templates, data-binding, polymer

It seems that when using a [single template](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#single-template-instances) through at least 2 layers of getters, the binding doesn't update anymore when the underlying value changes. Paradoxically this seems to work when using [iterative templates](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#iterative-templates) instead.

It's a bit hard to explain and I'm not 100% sure that's the reason why the binding fails so here is a minimal(ish) example to illustrate:

```
<polymer-element name="test-binding">
<template>
  <template bind="{{ getterMap }}">
    <span>{{ name }}</span>
  </template>
</template>
<script>
    (function(){
        Polymer('test-binding', {
            ready: function(){
                var getterMap = {};
                Object.defineProperty(this, 'getterMap', {
                    get: function(){ return getterMap; },
                    set: function(newValue){ getterMap = newValue; }
                });

                var name = 'foo';
                Object.defineProperty(getterMap, 'name', {
                    get: function(){ return name; },
                    set: function(newValue){ name = newValue; }
                });

                setInterval(function(){
                    this.getterMap.name = 'foo '+Math.random();
                }.bind(this), 2000);
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

And the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RFontana/eq0tnwb8/) that goes along with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little tweaking, it turns out that the normal template binding does not work with `Object.defineProperty` directly upon the object. Your list template works because it sticks the getterMap in an array on a property NOT defined by `Object.defineProperty`. After converting the list to Object.defineProperty, it stops working.

**Update:**

After further testing, it only applies to `get()`s and `set()`s. If the defineProperty is described with a `writable` `value` descriptor, it works just fine.

After doing some searching, this post on Google Groups reveals that getters/setters may not be used if you want to utilize data binding.

[Attributes and Observers vs Getters/Setters](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/hv8ipeS1K84)

**Update 2:**

According to [this issue discussion](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/277), you may add data-binding to object accessors, via Object.observe(). It requires the use of Object.getNotifier() and Notifier.notify(). However, use of this API comes with some concerns. To see it in use, check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RFontana/frr9zmqe/).

- The [Object.observe()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) API is part of the ES Harmony proposal. So, it is highly browser dependent.
- Currently, the only browser that supports it is Chrome.

Comment: there's a way to force binding updates through accessors, see my comment in this Polymer [issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/277). Would you mind to update your answer accordingly?